# PhpWord output doesn't work in LibreOffice but works fine in MS Word

Tags: php, ms-word, libreoffice, phpword

This relates to a semi-known issue listed on the GitHub page [[link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1515)], where the way PhpWord generates tables causes it to set the cell width to "", which isn't valid in LibreOffice, but is fine in Word.

The issue on GitHub lists html-to-word conversion specifically, but I'm getting this issue when just going by the regular object-oriented interface also.

I've tried manually setting the cell width, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm asking here to see if anyone has any workaround to this issue, as it makes it nearly impossible to debug my output on a Linux box without access to MS Word. I need to export .docx for a client.

Why not just export to .odt to test it instead? If I do that it won't render the list I have on the page either.....

Here's a rough outline of the document I'm working with (I'm not at liberty to share the exact code due to NDAs):

```
$document = new PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $document->addSection();

// This list doesn't get rendered in the ODT file
$section->addListItem('Employee ID: 98765');
$section->addListItem('First Name: John');
$section->addListItem('Last Name: Doe');
$section->addListItem('SSN: 12345');

// This table has errors in LibreOffice when exported to .docx
if ($show_adv_details) {
    $table = $section->addTable();
    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell()->addText('SSN');
    $table->addCell()->addText('Email');
    $table->addCell()->addText('Phone No');
    
    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell()->addText('12345');
    $table->addCell()->addText('jd@example.com');
    $table->addCell()->addText('999 1234');

    // repeat ad nauseam
}

$section->addTitle('Comment');
$section->addTitle('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.');
```

I'm using PHP 7.0 (ancient legacy system, can't do anything about it) on Ubuntu.

So just to reiterate the question here at the end:

Is there something I can do to make this document render correctly on all the different outputs? The documentation doesn't seem to be much help.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know anything about PHP or the internal structure of tables in Word. But I really want to help. Perhaps [**Listing 8.18: Create a text table and insert cells**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt) will tell you the missing line in your code? (I mean initializing the object right after it is created). Or perhaps you are looking for [**Description on this page**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TableColumnSeparator.html)

Comment: @JohnSUN if I had any idea how PhpWord worked internally, I'd be able to tell you anything useful regarding your questions.
Unfortunately, as it stands, I've mostly just gone off of examples found on the github page, and none of them mention anything being different between exporting between odt and docx besides declaring the type in the exporter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I'm not a maintainer from the PHPOffice package but here is a workaround which I made digging in the package code and fixing your two issues:

1. ODT List does not work;
2. Tables on Word2007 Writer when opening with LibreOffice does not work.

I realized that the **ListItem.php** class did not exist on ODText writer, and I suppose that this is why you can not add lists to .odt files.

You need to add the widths manually to columns to make it work on LibreOffice (as [Nigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren) said, you can go through each `addCell()` call and add some number, even "1" works).

## How to fix both issues

We will "override" the original files with some updates that fix the issues.
In order to make it work, you should have installed [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#installation) using Composer.
*(This is the only option available on the installation guide, but there are other ways to do that).*

Without Composer, require the custom files after PHPWord require (I think that it works). Or change directly the files on their locations (a bad idea).

### Files

Create a structure like that:

```
Custom
├── Element
│   └── Table.php
└── Writer
    └── ODText
        └── Element
            └── ListItem.php
```

Of course, you can use any other, but we're going to "override" the original package files, so I kept its structure.

We will use [Autoload Files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) to get those files:

**composer.json**:

```json
...
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "Custom/Element/Table.php",
        "Custom/Writer/ODText/Element/ListItem.php"
    ]
},
...
```

If there's no "autoload" key on your **composer.json**, you have to add it, and the same goes for the "files" key.

Run `composer dump-autoload` to update the changes.

### Custom classes

Now, we have to add the code to our custom files.

Custom/Writer/ODText/Element/**ListItem.php**:

```php
<?php
namespace PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\ODText\Element;

/**
 * ListItem element writer
 */
class ListItem extends AbstractElement
{
    /**
     * Write list item element.
     */
    public function write()
    {
        $xmlWriter = $this->getXmlWriter();
        $element = $this->getElement();
        if (!$element instanceof \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\ListItem) {
            return;
        }
        
        $textObject = $element->getTextObject();

        $xmlWriter->startElement('text:list');
        $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('text:style-name', 'L1');

        $xmlWriter->startElement('text:list-item');

        $xmlWriter->startElement('text:p');
        $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('text:style-name', 'P1');

        $elementWriter = new Text($xmlWriter, $textObject, true);
        $elementWriter->write();

        $xmlWriter->endElement(); // text:list
        $xmlWriter->endElement(); // text:p
        $xmlWriter->endElement(); // text:list-item
    }
}
```

The file has been adapted from the Word2007 version and fixes your first issue. Now lists will work on ODText.

Custom/Element/**Table.php**:

```php
<?php
namespace PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element;

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table as TableStyle;

/**
 * Table element writer
 */
class Table extends AbstractElement
{
    /**
     * Table style
     *
     * @var \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table
     */
    private $style;

    /**
     * Table rows
     *
     * @var \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Row[]
     */
    private $rows = array();

    /**
     * Table width
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $width = null;

    /**
     * Create a new table
     *
     * @param mixed $style
     */
    public function __construct($style = null)
    {
        $this->style = $this->setNewStyle(new TableStyle(), $style);
    }

    /**
     * Add a row
     *
     * @param int $height
     * @param mixed $style
     * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Row
     */
    public function addRow($height = null, $style = null)
    {
        $row = new Row($height, $style);
        $row->setParentContainer($this);
        $this->rows[] = $row;

        return $row;
    }

    /**
     * Add a cell
     *
     * @param int $width
     * @param mixed $style
     * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Cell
     */
    public function addCell($width = 1, $style = null)
    {
        $index = count($this->rows) - 1;
        $row = $this->rows[$index];
        $cell = $row->addCell($width, $style);

        return $cell;
    }

    /**
     * Get all rows
     *
     * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Row[]
     */
    public function getRows()
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    /**
     * Get table style
     *
     * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table
     */
    public function getStyle()
    {
        return $this->style;
    }

    /**
     * Get table width
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * Set table width.
     *
     * @param int $width
     */
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    /**
     * Get column count
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function countColumns()
    {
        $columnCount = 0;

        $rowCount = count($this->rows);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
            /** @var \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Row $row Type hint */
            $row = $this->rows[$i];
            $cellCount = count($row->getCells());
            if ($columnCount < $cellCount) {
                $columnCount = $cellCount;
            }
        }

        return $columnCount;
    }

    /**
     * The first declared cell width for each column
     *
     * @return int[]
     */
    public function findFirstDefinedCellWidths()
    {
        $cellWidths = array();

        foreach ($this->rows as $row) {
            $cells = $row->getCells();
            if (count($cells) <= count($cellWidths)) {
                continue;
            }
            $cellWidths = array();
            foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                $cellWidths[] = $cell->getWidth();
            }
        }

        return $cellWidths;
    }
}
```

As we are "overwriting" the file, we cannot reuse the original file extending it (at least, I don't know how). The only change here is on `public function addCell($width = 1, $style = null)` that makes always "1" as default value to the function. This fixes your second issue, and now you can call `$table->addCell()` without a value.

## DEMO

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $document->addSection();

// This list **does** get rendered in the ODT file
$section->addListItem('Employee ID: 98765');
$section->addListItem('First Name: John');
$section->addListItem('Last Name: Doe');
$section->addListItem('SSN: 12345');

$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell()->addText('SSN');
$table->addCell()->addText('Email');
$table->addCell()->addText('Phone No');

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell()->addText('12345');
$table->addCell()->addText('jd@example.com');
$table->addCell()->addText('999 1234');

// Save the document as DOCX
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($document, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('document.docx');

// Save the document as ODT
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($document, 'ODText');
$objWriter->save('document.odt');
```

Comment: Since I'm adding cells via a loop (I only did it by hand to outline the structure in the demo), setting the width to 1 isn't an issue, but including an alternate set of files seems to be a rather intense workaround. Unfortunately, setting the width to 1 doesn't result in a working file, as LibreOffice still says the docx is corrupted.

Comment: Actually the corruption seems to be unrelated. I'm currently battling that issue, as the library for inexplicable reasons now generates corrupt docx files, even without your changes

Comment: That's weird, even with the demo that I provided, the two file versions didn't work?

Comment: I honestly have no idea why the corruption occurs. When I sftp the file off the server I can open it just fine. If I open the file downloaded by the browser, libreoffice reports it to be corrupted. Note that I'm only talking about docx here. I was merely using odt for testing.

Comment: So weird, it seems like a problem in some other place... Try to enable/disable one thing after another on a new server to see if there's something, I don't know...

Comment: Yeah that's just it, nobody here in the office have any good ideas as to what might cause it.